# how to display a selected item on a list box (from an access database) to a text box?

Tags: database, vb.net, ms-access

Hi I'm trying to display a selected product on a listbox similar in this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QbbZzaMZGhY

In the video, when he click an item from the listbox, its values appear(price and name) on the textbox. I reviewed the source code but he was not using a database. In my case, I need to use an access database to list all of my product and their id and price. Here's what I got so far from asking here:

```
Private Sub listboxitems_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles listboxitems.SelectedIndexChanged
        Using lbconn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection("PROVIDER=Microsoft.ACE.Oledb.12.0; Data Source = C:\Users\USER PC\Desktop\orderDB1.accdb")
            Using lbcmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand("SELECT productid, product, price FROM productlog WHERE productid = ? AND product = ? AND price = ?", lbconn)

            'Set your values here.  The parameters must be added in the same order that they 
            'appear in the sql SELECT command
            Dim prodidparam As New OleDbParameter("@productid", Me.txtproductid.Text)
            Dim prodparam As New OleDbParameter("@product", Me.txtproduct.Text)
            Dim priceparam As New OleDbParameter("@price", Me.txtprice.Text)

            lbcmd.Parameters.Add(prodidparam)
            lbcmd.Parameters.Add(prodparam)
            lbcmd.Parameters.Add(priceparam)

            'Open the connection
            lbconn.Open()
            txtproduct.Text = listboxitems.SelectedItem
            Using lbreader As OleDbDataReader = lbcmd.ExecuteReader()
                While lbreader.Read
                    txtproductid.Text = lbreader.GetInt32("productid").ToString()
                    txtproduct.Text = lbreader.GetString("product")
                    txtprice.Text = lbreader.GetString("price").ToString()
                End While
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using

End Sub
```

In the line:
    txtproduct.Text = listboxitems.SelectedItem

I managed to show its name in the textbox, but its not coming from my database. I can't just type their price and name in the project but I need my data source to come from the database. So far nothing is showing up in the app. What am i missing? Thanks.

EDIT: The form load code where the listbox is filled with the database.

```
Private Sub shop_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'Create a connection to the database
    provider = "PROVIDER=Microsoft.ACE.Oledb.12.0; Data Source="
    datafile = "C:\Users\USER PC\Desktop\orderDB1.accdb"
    connString = provider & datafile
    myConnection.ConnectionString = connString

    'Open the connection with error handling
    Try
        If Not myConnection.State = ConnectionState.Open Then

        End If
        myConnection.Open()
    Catch OleDbExceptionErr As OleDbException
        MessageBox.Show(OleDbExceptionErr.Message)
    Catch InvalidOperationErr As InvalidOperationException


        MessageBox.Show(InvalidOperationErr.Message)
    End Try


    'Command Object. Select from productlog. 'productlog name of table'

    Dim objcmd As New OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM productlog", myConnection)

    'data adapter and data table.
    Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter(objcmd)
    Dim dt As New DataTable("productlog")
    da.Fill(dt)



    'Create connection and release resources
    myConnection.Close()
    myConnection.Dispose()
    myConnection = Nothing
    objcmd.Dispose()
    objcmd = Nothing
    da.Dispose()
    da = Nothing

    'fill from access to the listbox
    For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows
        listboxitems.Items.Add(row.Item("product"))
    Next



    'Release resources
    dt.Dispose()
    dt = Nothing
End Sub
```

EDIT: CODE UPDATED

```
Private Sub listboxitems_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles listboxitems.SelectedIndexChanged
    Using lbconn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection("PROVIDER=Microsoft.ACE.Oledb.12.0; Data Source = C:\Users\USER PC\Desktop\orderDB1.accdb")
        Using lbcmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand("SELECT productid, product, price FROM productlog WHERE product = ?", lbconn)

            'Set your values here.  The parameters must be added in the same order that they 
            'appear in the sql SELECT command
            Dim prodparam As New OleDbParameter("@product", listboxitems.SelectedItem)
            Dim prodidparam As New OleDbParameter("@productid", listboxitems.SelectedItem)
            Dim prodpriceparam As New OleDbParameter("@price", listboxitems.SelectedItem)


            lbcmd.Parameters.Add(prodparam)
            lbcmd.Parameters.Add(prodidparam)
            lbcmd.Parameters.Add(prodpriceparam)


            'Open the connection
            lbconn.Open()
            txtproduct.Text = listboxitems.SelectedItem
            Using lbreader As OleDbDataReader = lbcmd.ExecuteReader()
                While lbreader.Read
                    txtproductid.Text = listboxitems.SelectedItem.ToString()' iknow im missing alot in this line of code i just dont know what that is'
                    txtproduct.Text = listboxitems.SelectedItem.ToString()
                    txtprice.Text = listboxitems.SelectedItem.ToString()
                End While
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using

End Sub
```

I changed the get statements cause im having an error that says cannot convert type integer to string. im sorry if im making this really hard stack overflow is like my first line of defense and my last resort at the same time.

Comment: Learn to use the debugger to step through your code to see what is happening.  Since you are only expecting one record, use an `If lbreader.Read Then` instead of a loop, since you know you aren't looping.  Assuming you only have one productID per product, you won't need those other filters in your WHERE clause.  Your code is confused between supplying parameters and getting the results.  You probably have to get the productID from your listbox, which you aren't doing until it's too late.

Comment: Research the wonderful world of DataBinding.  If the ListBox has all the products, you dont have to go get the details when they select an item.  Use a DataTable as a DataSource.

Comment: Can you show the code that fills the ListBox with data from the database table?

Comment: @Plutonix databinding. aight got it. Im gonna do some research on that.

Comment: @Steve I edited it and added the code in my question.

Comment: Instead of adding rows, set the DisplayMember to product, ValueMember to productID and the DataSource to the dt.  Now when the listbox value changes, you can use the SelectedValue to supply your query with the proper productID.

Answer (score 1):

Your query is wrong. You want to get back the `productid`, `product` and `price` from the `productlog` table WHERE the record searched is equal to the productid, product and price that you supply as parameters.

Did you see the problem?

If you already know these values why ask the database? I suppose that your task is to find the product and price given the product stored in the current list item. If so, there is no need to use the textboxes and your query should be

```
SELECT productid, product, price FROM productlog WHERE product = ?
```

And the parameter is the data extracted by the listbox item

```
Dim prodidparam As New OleDbParameter("@product", listboxitems.SelectedItem)
```

Now your code could reach the while loop and set the textboxes with the missing informations. Of course this works because you have distinct product names in your table (meaning, there are no two records with the same product name)

**EDIT**
Looking at your comments below it seems that you are really confused how to use the GetPos, GetString, GetInt32 and eventually GetDecimal.
Once you have called *lbreader.Read()* you have a record at your disposition to transfer into your textboxes. But there is little point to take in consideration. You should call the various GetXXXX appropriate for the datatype of the underlying column. This problem is often overlooked by VB.NET programmers used to the automatic type conversion applied by the VB.NET compiler. These conversions don't exist in the lower levels of NET and it is better to avoid these conversions at all to not fall in subtle problems.

However, to call a `OleDbDatareader.GetXXXX` you need the ordinal position of the field in the returned record. So you need to call first `OleDbDataReader.GetPos` and then use the value returned by GetPos to extract the info from the GetXXXXX call.

```
Using lbreader As OleDbDataReader = lbcmd.ExecuteReader()
     While lbreader.Read
           Dim pos = lbreader.GetPos("product")
           txtProduct.Text = lbreader.GetString(pos)
           pos = lbreader.GetPos("productid")
           txtProductID.Text = lbreader.GetInt32(pos).ToString()
           pos = lbreader.GetPos("Price")
           txtPrice.Text = lbreader.GetDecimal(pos).ToString()
     End While
End Using
```

The last line uses GetDecimal assuming the column Price to be a numeric decimal in your database (as it should being it a currency value), if not, then use the appropriate GetXXXXX. Note also that the two last GetXXXX returns an Int32 and a Decimal. To assign these values to a property of type string (like Text) you should use an explicit conversion to a string (ToString())

Comment: ok i understand the error in the where statement now. but i haven't figured out yet what to do in the .getstring/.getint32 statements. Are those fine the way they are? I change my code and managed to display the productname on both the product and product id text boxes but not the price. i'll edit it in my question.

Comment: You call the database to get your data. It is the OleDbDataReader variable that has the info you want to display in the textboxes. The original code using the _lbreader_ was on the right track, but with an error. You cannot pass the field name to GetString, GetInt32 or GetDecimal, you pass the ordinal position in the query (in your case productid=0, product=1, price=2) or just lbreader.GetOrdinal("product") to get the same values. Also beware of the Price column. If this column is decimal on the db you use GetDecimal not GetString (invalid cast exception)

Comment: why am i getting an invalid error when my price and product id are set as numbers? product id is 1 and price is 10000. i tried getdecimal and getdouble they both got the error. when i use getstring theres none.

Comment: @JermaineAIT How do you have defined the type for these two fields in the _productlog_ table on the MS-Access database? You are reading from the table and thus you use the GetXXXX appropriate for the type defined in the database

Comment: in access design view, i set their data types to number and the product to text

Comment: OK, but number is not enough to decide which GetXXXX is correct. Look at the field properties below the schema. There you can see the exact datatype (long integer requires GetInt32, Decimal requires GetDecimal) and remember to use DECIMAL to have precise math with currency values

Comment: Im really confused. I set them in the database as long integers so its int32 right? But then you said I cannot pass the field name to GetXXXX. So how? I tried `txtproductid.Text = lbreader.GetOrdinal("productid")
                        txtproduct.Text = lbreader.GetOrdinal("product")
                        txtprice.Text = lbreader.GetOrdinal("price")` but it displayed their positions. txtproduct displayed 1, productid displayed 0, and price displayed 3.

Comment: Im getting an error that says GetPos is not a member. So its basically this, the other part of the code is right. But, the reader part has some errors. What i need to do is to get the position of the column using GetPos and return it to the textbox by using lbreader.GetXXXX. Is there other way to locate an exact entry in the database other than getpos? And is the `textbox.Text = reader.GetXXXX("column name").Tostring` statement correct?